# Import floating numbers from Google spreadsheets in CSV

Tags: import, csv-format

For some reason when importing some floating numbers, Mathematica does not interpret them correctly. For example this spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zddNRubvfaRx1ySDXFbqGl5ohPdjI9Eld1Fr3ERWliA/edit?usp=sharing

And this code:

```
Import["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/\
1zddNRubvfaRx1ySDXFbqGl5ohPdjI9Eld1Fr3ERWliA/export?format=csv", \
"CSV", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]
{{"2,15"}, {"2,45"}, {"1,88"}, {"2,35"}, {"11,35"}, {"2,08"}, {2272}, \
{"1,83"}, {"1,91"}, {"1,9"}}
```

See how 2,272 is incorrectly imported as 2272. Why is this the case, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `"NumberPoint"` option explicitly if you're importing numbers with [decimal commas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma):

```
ImportString["2,15
              2,45
              1,88
              2,35
              11,35
              2,08
              2,272
              1,83
              1,91
              1,9", "List", "NumberPoint" -> ","]
   {2.15, 2.45, 1.88, 2.35, 11.35, 2.08, 2.272, 1.83, 1.91, 1.9}
```